# ASP.NET Javascript Resource Handler

Tags: asp.net, javascript, ashx

I would like to make a Handler that takes all of my Javascript files i need and compresses and merges them, something like the scriptmanager of asp.net does.
Is this possible? i thought on an .ashx handler, but i'm not sure if this works..

would be cool if you also could do this with the css files.

Comment: Certainly possible, ashx will be a good choice. However you should ask yourself why would you want to do it? Do you really need a set of scripts that have dynamic content/behaviour? Or some other reasons? Share with us! :-)

Comment: i think it would be nice to have just one script tag in the header which handles the compressing and merging of all my files so that i dont have to do it always manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know, ASP.NET supports Script Combining:

```
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488552.aspx
http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=13356
```

Also, you could just use something like HTTP Compression and a good caching strategy:

```
http://www.port80software.com/products/httpzip/
http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/d52ff289-94d3-4085-bc4e-24eb4f312e0e.mspx
```

At the end of the day, using both techniques together is the optimal strategy.